# Swift 5- Firebase- Putting users into sections with data loaded from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, tableview, sections

I have a tableview that has a list of users in a directory that are loaded in from a firebase directory. My question is how can i put them into sections similarly to that of the contact app in the iPhone. I want each user to be displayed by their name under the appropriate sections.

here is the code I have:

my main view controller:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    //MARK: - variables for the textfield search
    @IBOutlet var field: UITextField!
    var filteredTable = [String]()
    
    //MARK: - Variables for the tableview data from Firebase
    var table = [FacStaffInfo]()
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    
    @IBOutlet weak var Tableview: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //MARK: - setting the delegate for the test field for filter
        
        field.delegate = self

        //MARK: - This is all the functionality for the loading from Firebase to the TableView

        ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")
        
        ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                self.table.removeAll()
                
                for user in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
                    
                    let object = user.value as? [String: AnyObject]
                    let title = object?["title"]
                    let name = object?["name"]
                    let email = object?["email"]
                    let phone = object?["phone"]
                    let office = object?["office"]
                    let bio = object?["bio"]

                    let user = FacStaffInfo(title: title as! String, name: name as! String, email: email as! String, phone: phone as! Int, office: office as! String, bio: bio as! String)

                    self.table.append(user)
                    
                        self.Tableview.reloadData()
                    
                    
                    
                }
            }
        })
        
    }
}


//MARK: - add the tableview functions

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        //MARK: - adding functionality for textfield search
        if !filteredTable.isEmpty {
            return table.count
            
        }
        
        //MARK: - just returning the array from the database, keep if remove textfield crap
        return table.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell") as! TableViewCell
        
        let user: FacStaffInfo
        
        user = table[indexPath.row]
        cell.titleLabel?.text = user.title
        cell.nameLabel?.text = user.name
        cell.emailLabel?.text = user.email
        cell.phoneLabel?.text = String(user.phone)
        cell.officeLabel?.text = user.office
        cell.bioLabel?.text = user.bio
        
        //MARK: - testing using arrays to filter tableview data
        
//        if !filteredTable.isEmpty {
//            cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTable[indexPath.row]
//        }
//        else {
//            cell.textLabel?.text = table.
//        }
//
//
//
//
//
       return cell


    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
            }
    
    
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

            if let indexPath = Tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let destinationController = segue.destination as! InfoViewController

                destinationController.FacStaffData = table[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my data model

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase


class FacStaffInfo {
    
    var title: String
    var name: String
    var email: String
    var phone: Int
    var office: String
    var bio: String
    
    init(title: String, name: String, email: String, phone: Int, office: String, bio: String) {
        self.title = title;
        self.name = name;
        self.email = email;
        self.phone = phone;
        self.office = office;
        self.bio = bio
        
        
        
    }
}
```

This is my table view cell

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
  
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var officeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bioLabel: UILabel!

    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Swift 5

Declare your class as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    // MARK: Outlets
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Tableview: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var field: UITextField!
    
    // MARK: Properties
    
    var sectionNames: [String] = []
    var users: [String: [FacStaffInfo]] = [:]
    
    var ref: DatabaseReference!

    // MARK: View Controller Life Cycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getUsersFromFirebaseDB()
    }
    
    deinit
    {
        ref.removeAllObservers()
    }
    
    // MARK: Private Methods
    
    private func usersFetched(_ usersData: [FacStaffInfo])
    {
        for user in usersData
        {
            guard let userNameFirstChar = user.name.first?.uppercased() else { continue }
            if var usersForKey = users["\(userNameFirstChar)"]
            {
                usersForKey.append(user)
                users["\(userNameFirstChar)"] = usersForKey
            }
            else
            {
                // no users are stored in dictionary for key userNameFirstChar
                users["\(userNameFirstChar)"] = [user]
            }
        }
    
        // sort dictionary keys and set it in sectionNames
        sectionNames = users.map { $0.key }.sorted()
    }
    
    private func getUsersFromFirebaseDB()
    {
        ref = Database.database().reference().child("users")
        ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { [weak self] (snapshot) in
    
            guard snapshot.childrenCount > 0 else { return }
    
            var users: [FacStaffInfo] = []
            for user in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
            {
                let object = user.value as? [String: AnyObject]
    
                let title = object?["title"]
                let name = object?["name"]
                let email = object?["email"]
                let phone = object?["phone"]
                let office = object?["office"]
                let bio = object?["bio"]
    
                let user = FacStaffInfo(title: title as! String, name: name as! String, email: email as! String, phone: phone     as! Int, office: office as! String, bio: bio as! String)
                users.append(user)
            }
    
            self?.usersFetched(users)
            self?.Tableview.reloadData()
        })
    }
    
    // MARK: Navigation
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)
    {
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail"
        {
            if let indexPath = Tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow
            {
                let destinationController = segue.destination as! InfoViewController
                let char = sectionNames[indexPath.section]
                let user = users[char]![indexPath.row]
                destinationController.FacStaffData = user
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, add the following extension:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
{
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        sectionNames.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?
    {
        sectionNames[section]
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        let char = sectionNames[section]
        return users[char]!.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userCell") as! TableViewCell
        let char = sectionNames[indexPath.section]
        let user = users[char]![indexPath.row]
        cell.nameLabel?.text = user.name
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: First off, Thank you very much! But i have one more question. I am still new to this and this is my first in depth application but when you say to get the data and send it to that function. How do you mean?

Comment: Okay, I think a couple more questions. So i put the usersNamesFetched Function right beneath my table.append but above my Tableview.reload, that didnt give me an error but is that the right spot? Also, When i run it now I get nothing showing up on my tableview

Comment: I have updated the answer, check it again, and let's see what will happen!

Comment: Do you mean to replace what i already have in my viewDidLoad? because when I first built it i made it take me to a detailViewController with information about that cell. So do i put that getUsersFromFirebaseDB instead? or just place it after it?

Comment: Yes, replace what you have done in viewDidLoad with getUsersFromFirebaseDB

Comment: I have updated the main view controller at the bottom but i am getting the warning "let userName = users[char]![indexPath.row]" now and it is not loading my users into my tableview

Comment: Also after function getUsersFromFirebaseDB, check array content

Comment: The previous code is from a working project, this should work with you. Try again.

Comment: Whenever this works with you, you should mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Hey Sorry. I am testing out it now. I was offline last night

Comment: So I need to put my User info after the getUsersFromFirebaseDB but before the reload table?

Comment: Just call getUsersFromFirebaseDB in viewDidLoad

Comment: Could you check the updated viewcontroller 2, and see if this if this is the right setup?

Comment: I have updated the answer and put detail solution, try it

Comment: Okay, Ill go and check out more implementations of how these works. Thanks

Comment: I have solved your code and run it, just a moment and I will update answer

Comment: @MattyJay94 I have pasted the answer and tested it, just copy the code and run it! then read it well to understand every line. Best regards. Do not forget to mark the accepted answer and vote the answer to reach others.